# Passing std::map by reference to constructor of class not updating map

Tags: c++, class, reference, stdmap

I'm trying to understand why in the case of a class which has a reference to a std::map, it doesn't update the map that is referenced outside the scope of the class.

Here's my test program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
protected:
    int x;
};

class FooTest
{
public:
    FooTest(std::map<string, Foo*> & f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }
    void func()
    {
        f["try"] = new Foo(3);
    }

protected:
    std::map<string, Foo*> f;
};
```

Followed by the main that does some basic instructions :

```
int main()
{
    std::map<string, Foo*> f;
    f["ok"] = new Foo(1);
    FooTest test(f);
    test.func();

    for(std::map<string, Foo*>::iterator it = f.begin(); it != f.end(); ++it) {
        it->second->display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this displays `1` whereas I would like to have `1` and then `3`.
I tried passing by reference the map to the function func, and this worked well, the map was nicely "updated". Obviously, I'm missing something from the constructor, that for some reasons creates a new map and doesn't update anymore the map that I gave in the main function.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `std::map<string, Foo*> f;` should be `std::map<string, Foo*> & f;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be passing the map by reference, but your data member is not a reference:

```
std::map<string, Foo*> f;
```

So when you do this

```
this->f = f;
```

you make a copy of the input parameter `f`. This simple code illustrates the problem:

```
void foo(int& i)
{
  int j = i;
  j = 42; // modifies `j`, not i`.
}
```

Comment: Yea, I think I see why I am getting this wrong. I believed that having a pointer to Foo would be enough, but if I understand, when I create the key "try", it is only created on the map that has been copied, right ?

Comment: @Hawknight Yes, exactly. It affects the data member `f`, which not a reference.

Comment: I would need to use a proper pointer to circumvent this problem, right ?

Comment: @Hawknight Is it really a problem? You can use a reference or a pointer, depending on what you want the class to behave like. Bear in mind that references are not assignable or "copyable". They just refer to an object.

Comment: I'd like to update my map from the class, so I would need to create a pointer to my map in the main, and just pass my pointer to the function. That's how I would see it..

Comment: @Hawknight if it's not a typo as I primarily thought, then use a pointer. It's better to use references for arguments that are used only in the scope of a function.